# RadTree - How to save expanded state

Tags: .net-4.6, radtreeview

We are using Telerik 2017.1.228.45 RadTree controls. We have implemented RadTree contract inside a usercontrol and it's getting called through a master page. all Radtree nodes has a customUrl field populated,so when they are clicked on the same page, a user control appears and when some changes are made to that user control and is closed, RadTree loses its expanded state.

​
Is there a way to persist RadTree in that expanded state please? if yes, then how or if you could point me towards the right direction, that'll be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has solved my issue:

http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/save-the-expanded-state-of-the-treenodes-when-the-treeview-is-being-bound-upon-each-postback